# How to test recurring payment on stripe subscription for due bill?

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription

I have created subscription using stripe api for 1 month interval.

```
 const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create(
  {
    customer: customer.id,
    items: [
      {
        price: productPrice.id,
      },
    ],
   // payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
    expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
    application_fee_percent: fee,
  },
  {
    stripeAccount: accountId,
  }
);
```

Subscription created successfully based on product and price.but i can't wait for 1 month (next billing) for testing so i need to test now how will work for next payment.it will auto deduct from payment method? or customer will notify about next due and have to pay? there need more code for it?

Answer (score 3):

Stripe has a feature called [Test Clocks](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks) that allows to move subscriptions forward in time. So you could create a subscription with a test clock, then advance the clock by one month to see exactly what happens.

But to answer your question: if the customer (or the subscription) has a default payment method set, then yes Stripe will automatically attempt to make a payment at the end of every billing cycle.

Comment: Before that feature existed, you could also set the subscription duration to a day instead of a month in the testing environment.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes I also had in mind that in test mode the subscript run out after a few minutes on default. Any idea if I can reenable this feature or do I need to use Test Clocks now?